# JTable .. colour of selected row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in Java that has a custom dataMOdel and custom renderer. Now when i select some cell it has a dark blue border around it. I want the selected row to be all highlighted in some colour. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use custom table cell renderer. Check out the tutorial here: [http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)